# Get instances from a DLL/Assembly?

Tags: c#, dll

I got the following code that generates a DLL :

```
public class MyObject : DependencyObject
{
}


public class Timer : DependencyObject
{
}

public class AnotherClass
{
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyObject q1 = new MyObject();
        MyObject q2 = new MyObject();
        MyObject q3 = new MyObject();
        MyObject q4 = new MyObject();

        Timer t1 = new Timer();
        Timer t2 = new Timer();
        Timer t3 = new Timer();

        AnotherClass a1 = new AnotherClass();
        AnotherClass a2 = new AnotherClass();
        AnotherClass a3 = new AnotherClass();
    }
}
```

Then I'd like to extract instances from my DLL file. Here is what I got for the moment :

```
var library = Assembly.LoadFrom(libraryPath);
```

But then, I havent any idea about how to extract my 10 instances (4 MyObjects, 3 Timers & 3 AnotherClasses). The only thing I managed to get is the 4 classes (MyObject, Timer, AnotherClass and Test) with the code :

```
IEnumerable<Type> types = library.GetTypes();
```

but I think this is not the way I'll get my 10 instances...

(ps : I'm not even sure that the 10 instances are contained in my DLL file...)

Comment: You are confusing *types* and *objects*.  The objects that Main() creates are referenced by local variables, you cannot get to them.  They are also not in any way associated with the DLL, they live in the garbage collected heap like any other object.  Assemblies contain code, not data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question doesn't make any sense.

Those instances only exist as you execute `Main()`.

If `Main()` contains a loop that depends on user input, what would you want to get?